# Trying to find a member and receive Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this code and it shows me this error: *"Cannot read property 'get' of undefined."*

How can I fix it? The problematic line has a comment above it.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'mod',
  description: 'Mod command',
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();

    const InsufficientPermissions = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setDescription('Insufficient permissions!');

    if (!message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      message.channel.send(InsufficientPermissions);
    }

    const SpecifyMember = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setDescription('Please specify a user!');
    const ModAdded = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setDescription(`Mod was added to <@${target}>`);

    // THE LINE BELOW IS THE PROBLEM
    const member = message.member.cache.get(target.id);

    if (!target) {
      message.channel.send(SpecifyMember);
    } else {
      member.roles.add('803548878396981258', '816377135887286292');

      message.channel.send(ModAdded);
    }
  },
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. One important section of that article is titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific question". The current title does not. Please also [edit] your question to include any research you've done about what is one of the most common errors in JavaScript and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [`message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) returns the author of the message as a guild member so it won't have a `cache` property. You could use [`message.guild.members.cache.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members).

But, instead of getting `message.mentions.users`, you could get `message.mentions.members`. This way you don't have to get the member object from the user:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'mod',
  description: 'Mod command',
  execute(message, args, Discord) {
    const target = message.mentions.members.first();

    const InsufficientPermissions = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setDescription('Insufficient permissions!');

    if (!message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      message.channel.send(InsufficientPermissions);
    }

    const SpecifyMember = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FF0000')
      .setDescription('Please specify a user!');
    const ModAdded = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setDescription(`Mod was added to <@${target}>`);


    if (!target) {
      message.channel.send(SpecifyMember);
    } else {
      target.roles.add('803548878396981258', '816377135887286292');

      message.channel.send(ModAdded);
    }
  },
};
```